# Github App Node Middleware rejects all requests when behind a custom path

Tags: node.js, typescript, github, github-app, octokit-js

Using Octokit 3.1.2, this does not work:

```
import { createServer } from "node:http"
import { App, createNodeMiddleware } from "octokit"

const app = new App({
  ...
})

createServer(createNodeMiddleware(app.webhooks, { path: "/myapi/github/webhooks" })).listen(3001)
```

The middleware rejects all requests.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the options for Middleware have changed, [as per this documentation on octokit/app.js](https://github.com/octokit/app.js/?tab=readme-ov-file#createnodemiddlewareapp-options).  The above code must be changed to the following to work:

```
createServer(createNodeMiddleware(app, { pathPrefix: "/myapi/github" })).listen(3001)
```

Note that both the behavior (path is now a path prefix) *and* the default value (`/api/github/webhooks` -> `/api/github`) have changed!

This burned over five hours of my time! I filed a bug here. https://github.com/octokit/webhooks.js/issues/946